# Typescript connect primitive generic type with typeof method returns derived type

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a class with a value. The value might be of type string or number. Depending on the type of the value, I want to parse a different value to the same type.
So if value is of type string. I want to parse a given value to string.

The code works, but my typings are wrong. Is there a way that the compiler shows that `typeOfValue` is "string"?

Here is my current solution. I know that there is an issue with my typing in the `typeOfValue` method:

```ts
class MyClass<T extends string | number> {
    public constructor(private value: T) {
    }
    
    public typeOfValue(): `${T}` {
        return typeof this.value as `${T}`;
    }
}

const foo = new MyClass('foo');
// I want "theType" to be of type 'string' but it is of type 'foo'
const theType = foo.typeOfValue();
```

I understand that T is 'foo' because the type 'foo' extends the type 'string'. So typescript is setting T to the type 'foo'. But at this point I want the base type 'string'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a type to mimic the `typeof` operator:

```
type TypeOf<T> =
    T extends Function ? "function" :
    T extends object | null ? "object" :
    T extends string ? "string" :
    T extends number ? "number" :
    T extends boolean ? "boolean" :
    T extends undefined ? "undefined" :
    T extends symbol ? "symbol" :
    T extends bigint ? "bigint" :
    never;
```

then you can just assert that the return type is `TypeOf<T>`

```
class MyClass<T extends string | number> {
    public constructor(private value: T) {
    }
    
    public typeOfValue() {
        return typeof this.value as TypeOf<T>;
    }
}
```

and it'll work as expected:

```
const foo = new MyClass('foo');

const theType = foo.typeOfValue();
//    ^? "string"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEHkBmAeGA+KBeAsAKCkNiggA9gIA7AEwGcoAxAV0oGNgBLAe0qgH4oAIiQt23SoKgAufEWJkKNelwBGAKwjsoAHyiUmAGwP8hqje0kyCRGCXJU6UWsABOHSgHMTg528+XZGztFR30AWxUIF29wyJcA60JbBQd6FS4uAwgAQ14BQXTMnIlpQKTg1KgWaggkdwhqb2ra+uoEuWT7JScQCMzvWl70g3aglO6VDg93YG9J6cpgUcJKCAA3KIBufHxWA2zaegBZEABhfcO0Cu7fdy9dWKjMAG8yqDAmFQMOVihWHl8THYXBcAAowG41tkKFAoQYmBApLAAJRQV6JKAAXzebw+Xx+UFAkGQADVsvCIKDUei5HIXBBgEwXLwiRAuEhCQALDi0AB0cIRUAOsHgyDQ6G2GOxeGluwBsyQGWweggAHcoCdzgdaKCAOSKri65GSuWUZxciBwSDKg281mk8kIqmbIA)